# What is the status of setting environment variables without ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: environment-variables

[LWN.net - GNOME, Wayland, and environment variables](https://lwn.net/Articles/709769/)

> Strode, for all that he wants to move on to a "modern" solution for environment variables, is clearly feeling the pressure that comes from wider exposure of a broken system. Thus, his most recent comment on the bug, as of this writing, reads: "Yea, I'm considering caving on this." So Fedora 25 is likely to see an update that restores the login shell to the login process; a "proper fix" will wait for later.

It's now Fedora 28... where are we on the "proper fix" side of things?  Is there a forward-looking way for users to set environment variables for their sessions yet?

I.e a replacement for `~/.bash_profile` which works on Fedora, and hopefully elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For GNOME 3.24, Strode [reverted gnome-session](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736660#c103) to load environment variables by running a login shell.

In the same comment, they included a patch for gnome-session to push these session environment variables to systemd user services.  These include `gnome-terminal`, so it's fairly important :).

---

The GDM session launcher was already [patched](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/commit/448134d3cdbc54e5359ea33d387993b0defdaefa) in 3.22, to import the environment from `systemd --user`.  So the systemd environment is imported into the session, then modified by the login shell, and the result is also copied back to `systemd --user`.

Which should work ok... except testing on Fedora 28, it doesn't work properly for e.g. PATH, because the gdm sesssion launcher doesn't allow systemd environment variables to overwrite the pre-existing environment. [I've reported it on the GNOME issue tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/issues/385).

It was [agreed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3904#issuecomment-246361436) that `login` (for the text console) *could* accept some patch to load environment configuration before starting the users shell, but there's no change so far in [util-linux v2.32](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commits/v2.32/login-utils/).

I haven't even bothered looking for ssh patches :).

The systemd environment was already configurable in `user.conf`. As part of this effort, systemd v233 [gained](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/5131) an `environment.d/` format, that now supports e.g. prepending an extra directory to the existing `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` search lists.

---

I thought the best place to set environment variables for user logins would be in a PAM module - we even have `pam_env` already.  [The logic being](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3904#issuecomment-243192869)

> asking login, gdm, sshd (that'll never happen), etc. to do this is really a poor solution.

Unfortunately, the configuration of `pam_env` is annoyingly inconsistent between distros... and it seems there might have been a good reason for that.  The `~/.pam_environment` feature [is considered a big "footgun" for security](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3904#issuecomment-243484698). See also [CVE-2010-4708](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2010-4708).

> > Look at `pam_exec` for instance. You could imagine a sysadmin using it to do some postlogin configuration or something, but a user could
> >     get root by setting LD_PRELOAD. Or pam_selinux actually uses
> >     pam_getenv directly, so a user could screw with it. But my point isn't
> >     really these specific examples, it's just to illustrate there are
> >     risks from doing it as root, and we can bypass those risks entirely,
> >     eliminating a whole class of potential security bugs, by doing it just
> >     a little later in the login process. As a general rule, if you don't
> >     need code to run as root, it shouldn't run as root! Of course, I'm
> >     still torn, because logistically, it's more awkward to do it later,
> >     but there's no question in my mind that doing it as root is riskier
> >     than doing it as the user.
>
> The pam_exec manual explicitly states: "Commands called by pam_exec
>   need to be aware of that the user can have controll [sic] over the
>   environment."
>
> > re. pam_env, note fedora puts it top of the pam stack and disables ~/.pam_environment by default.
>
> Putting it at the top of the stack is a bug and violates the explicit
>   warning not to do this: "Since setting of PAM environment variables
>   can have side effects to other modules, this module should be the last
>   one on the stack."
>
> [...] Given the confusion here, this is obviously a footgun

The general idea of using the shell configuration for this also appears to work e.g. on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 graphical login.  There is one difference, however.  Fedora creates `~/.bash_profile` by default, which (for bash) causes `~/.profile` to be ignored.  Ubuntu and other Debian-based distributions create `~/.profile` by default instead.  (I.e. these files are provided when you create a new user, from `/etc/skel`).

(I have used this on Ubuntu recently.  Ubuntu seems to have changed over time w.r.t running a login shell for GUI sessions.  E.g. see https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980, https://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced, ["Why isn't gnome-terminal a login shell"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1699229&p=12031935#post12031935), and ["What shell login means ('bash -l')"](https://rvm.io/support/faq#what-shell-login-means-bash-l)).