# key binding to increment/decrement virtual console in X

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-consoles

One can change virtual consoles (or virtual terminals, VTs) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> (where <kbd>Fn</kbd> represents <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.). In addition, when not running `X`, one can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the arrow keys to cycle through VTs (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to decrement and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to increment the virtual terminal).

However, if `X` is running on one of the VTs, the arrow key bindings are not typically set and one must fall back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> to change to another VT.

I generally prefer using the arrow bindings to change VTs. To avoid having to switch between key bindings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> for VTs with `X`; arrows for VTs without it), to what command would one bind <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←/→</kbd> for decrementing/incrementing the VT in `X`?

In case the answer depends on the system, I am running debian and using dwm and openbox as window managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only tell you a dirty workaround.
Use [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) and add to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR-1))"
   alt + c:113

"sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR+1))"
   alt + c:114
```

If you don't have XDG_VTNR variable, then you have to hardcode previous/next vt.

You also have to put yourself into `/etc/sudoers`:

```
USER ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I do have the XDG_VTNR environment variable, but the virtual terminal is not responding to Alt+left or Alt+right. If I press either key combination after running `xbindkeys -n`, I get the following error message: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified".

Comment: Do you have `$XDG_VTNR` variable?

Comment: Then try to figure out which parameters are accepted by chvt.

Comment: The chvt command works (e.g., if I type `sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR+1))` into `xterm`, then my VT changes appropriately), so the problem is upstream (at the`xbindkeys` step).

Comment: You haven't added the line to sudoers, and it's waiting for password.
`USER` is your username, of course.

Comment: I tried `myusername ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt`, `myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt`, and `myusername ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt` in `/etc/sudoers`, where `myusername` is the output of `whoami`.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be that you have problems with sudo. Ask another question, sudo is not of my favourites. (I tested what I wrote and at least it works for me)

Comment: The problem was that the line in `sudoers` had to be at the end of the file. The standard line `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` was apparently overriding the settings.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that remains constant as you switch from VT to X11 and back is the "low-level" generic Linux input device handling subsystem.
 There are examples in C in [Linux USB Input Subsystem](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6396) and [part 2](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429) in Linux Journal. Your system may have a Python library [python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to make this easier.

To try out what is possible, `evtest` can be used to simply dump the events on a given input device, and you can track the state of the keys that interest you with an `awk` script or similar, and get it to issue the `chvt` commands.

Answer (score 0):

The Alt+Arrow keys become available to you if you are in XLATE mode. If you are not, you can activate it by using [the magic sysrq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key): an escape hatch in your kernel for when X locks up.

First, make sure it is on:

```bsh
cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

The output is a number, and you can switch into XLATE if it is either 1, or bitmask 0x4 is set: `x == 1 || x & 0x4`. [Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html)

If neither is true you can change the number as root:

```bsh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

On Arch Linux I can alternatively do:

```bsh
sysctl kernel.sysrq=1
```

Finally, either press `Alt+SysRq+R` or run the command below:

```bsh
echo r > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

You are now in XLATE mode- you have been blessed with handy key bindings until you reboot! For possible side effects, [see this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/what-is-raw-keyboard-mode).

Somebody please tell me if you can turn this on permanently.