# invoking password-less sudo via xbindkeys

Tags: sudo, xbindkeys, chvt

I tried to set up key bindings for changing the virtual terminal (VT) in `X`, as described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401060/14960). Typing `sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR-1))` into a terminal emulator appropriately changes the VT. However, I find that running `chvt` with elevated privileges works only when executed as a command to a terminal emulator (e.g., `xterm -e`), a requirement that I am trying to circumvent.

To describe my setup:

The following line was added to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
me    ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt
```

where `me` is the output of `whoami`. I also tried variations on this line (e.g., `me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt` and `me ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/chvt`)

To `~/.xbindkeysrc`, I added key bindings, either:

```
"sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR-1))"
   alt + c:113

"sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR+1))"
   alt + c:114
```

or

```
"sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR-1))"
   m:0x8 + c:113

"sudo chvt $(($XDG_VTNR+1))"
   m:0x8 + c:114
```

The first was suggested by the author of the linked post and the latter was determined by running `xbindkeys -k` on my system.

The key bindings failed and I ran `xbindkeys` in non-daemon mode to investigate. Pressing Alt+left or Alt+right while running `xbindkeys -n` gives the following error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Changing the command in `~/.xbindkeysrc` to `xterm -e sudo chvt ...` produces a working key binding (but at the cost of opening an `xterm` instance and prompting for a password), which confirms that the lack of a `tty` is the issue. How can the invocation of `sudo` in `.xbindkeys` be achieved without first summoning a `terminal`?

System details: debian v9.2., dwm v6.1, openbox v.3.6.1, xbindkeys v1.8.6, sudo v1.8.19p1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security-sensible default (or at least put in your distribution's default sudoers) is to not allow a sudo command without a tty, in order to prevent privilege escalation from a breach in an application. The command run with a shortcut has no tty, so it won't run. You could disable this setting globally, but it's better to disable it for everything except this command. The option is named `requiretty`:

```
Cmnd_Alias    CHVT = /bin/chvt
me            ALL = NOPASSWD: CHVT
Defaults!CHVT !requiretty
```

The first `!` means what follows is a Cmnd_Alias, the second `!` is the logical not operator. So running chvt is exempted from requiretty. Here the use of Cmnd_Alias wasn't needed, but should you use a command with options, or want to disable requiretty for two commands the syntax requires it.

NOTE: Some other settings might cancel some of these lines. So putting it last in sudoers might be required. It appears the OP also needed to do this to have it working, perhaps because of `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. I get the same error message ("sudo: no tty/askpass ...") after adding what you wrote to `/etc/sudoers`. If I omit `sudo` from the `xbindkeys` file, then I instead get `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the consol` (which is the same error I get when typing `chvt N` into a terminal without `sudo`).

Comment: use `sudo -l` and see if you see `Defaults!/bin/chvt !requiretty` in the result. Maybe an other part of your configuration erases this setting

Comment: Yes, it is present: "Runas and Command-specific defaults for <me>:
    Defaults!/bin/chvt !requiretty" (command alias substitution has taken place). I might also note that my `/etc/sudoers` file does not set `requiretty` generally.

Comment: Same result: `$ setsid sudo chvt 7 </dev/null  \n

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`