# detecting held keys with xbindkeys

Tags: x11, xbindkeys

I am using `xbindkeys` to bind Alt+left and Alt+right to `chvt` in order to cycle through virtual terminals, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401060/14960). I modified the arithmetic to be modular with respect to the number of virtual terminals available (six). I launch an `xbindkeys` daemon for each instance of a window manager (e.g., before starting dwm on tty1 and likewise for openbox on tty2); i.e., each tty has its own `xbindkeys` instance.

Apparently, `xbindkeys` can only detect nascent key press events, and not residually held keys. Thus, if I press Alt+right from `tty1` to switch to `tty2` and then want to continue on to `tty3`, I must release both keys and re-press both to advance. With non-`X` ttys, I can either hold both keys or keep <kbd>Alt</kbd> depressed while tapping the arrow key. Can this functionality (i.e., key-press memory) be replicated with `xbindkeys`? Since I apparently need multiple instances (one per WM, as stated), and the program (`xbindkeys`) appears to detect nascent key press events rather than held keys, it may not be possible. Any workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To continue with what you have currently developed, you can use the **evemu** tools package(s) to use the utilities `evtest` and `evemu-event`. List the input event devices with `sudo evtest` and find the line corresponding to your keyboard. I have a special keyboard so I got:

```
/dev/input/event2:      HID 05f3:0007
```

Now choose that number (2 in my case) and press the key you want to recognise (Alt for you). I used left shift and got

```
Event: time 15094562, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 15094562, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e1
Event: time 15094562, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT), value 1
```

We see here I got a type EV_KEY event with code KEY_LEFTSHIFT getting value 1 when I pressed shift, and a similar event with value 0 when I released it.

You can now simply query the state of this key at any time, for example after the chvt. Use, in my case,

```
sudo evtest --query  /dev/input/event2 EV_KEY KEY_LEFTSHIFT
```

The return code from this command is 0 if the value is 0, and 10 if the value is 1. You can use `echo $?` to show this value.

Knowing the state of the key, you can now emulate a keypress event so that the X11 server sees the "current" state. In my case, I would do

```
sudo evemu-event /dev/input/event2 --type EV_KEY --code KEY_LEFTSHIFT --value 1
```

As you might imagine, there is probably a simpler solution to your original problem. Instead of using `xbindkeys` and having this problem fixed here, you might look at a different solution using libevent. There are examples in C in [Linux USB Input Subsystem](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6396) and [part 2](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429) in Linux Journal. Your system may have a Python library [evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for the many suggestions. I will start by having a look at libevent, since it would be nice to use one interface across all ttys, rather than switching between interfaces as I enter/exit X11-enabled ttys.